# react native conditionally visible tabBarComponent

Tags: react-native, navigation

I build react native app and I want to make the tabBarComponent of TabNavigator visible\not visible in some screens.

```
    const Tabs = TabNavigator('MainTabs',
{
    NestedNavigatorStack: {
        screen: Home,
    },
    Search: { screen: Search },
    Cart: { screen: Cart },
    WishList: { screen: WishList },
    Profile: { screen: Profile },

}, {
    initialRouteName: 'NestedNavigatorStack',
    lazy: false,
    animationEnabled: true, 
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarComponent: TabBarHeader,
    navigationOptions :{
        tabBarVisible: true //TODO: change dinmaclly :hideTabBarComponents.includes(NavigationStore.CurrentRoute)
    }


})
```

what I tried to do is declare array of name route names I want to hide the tabBar when the I'm on the screen

```
export const hideTabBarComponents = [
    'Search',
    'Cart',
    'Profile',
    'WishList'
]
```

then to make condition (when includes return true so I hide it by !true)

```
 navigationOptions :{
    tabBarVisible: !hideTabBarComponents.includes(NavigationStore.CurrentRoute)
}
```

into

```
    const Tabs = TabNavigator('MainTabs',
{
    NestedNavigatorStack: {
        screen: Home,
    },
    Search: { screen: Search },
    Cart: { screen: Cart },
    WishList: { screen: WishList },
    Profile: { screen: Profile },

}, {
    initialRouteName: 'NestedNavigatorStack',
    lazy: false,
    animationEnabled: true, 
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarComponent: TabBarHeader,
    navigationOptions :{
        tabBarVisible: hideTabBarComponents.includes(NavigationStore.CurrentRoute) // the condition
    }


})
```

it works, but the issue when the screen change it's no 'build' the tabNavigator again, the tabNavigator is called one time when the app is load in first time, then it's not change. I'm looking for way to call it when the screen changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting up tabBar visibility when configuring tabBar will not change the behavior dynamically.You must use navigationOptions inside your component class and use tabBarVisible to show or hide the tabBar when mounting the screen.

```
class Screen1 extends Component {
   static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: 'Screen1',
            tabBarVisible: false,
        }
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { };
    }
};
```